# How to check whether the phone number is exists in contact DB or not using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mobile

Here is my code.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            var options = new ContactFindOptions();
          options.filter = "9898989898"; 
        //sample number like this(98 98989898) or (9898 9898 98) are not working form phone contact DB which can not be edited
        filter = ["displayName", "phoneNumbers"];
        navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
        }
        function onSuccess(contacts) {
            for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(contacts[i]));
            }
        };
        function onError(contactError) {
            alert('onError!');
        }
```

So here i am getting result for contact which is looks exactly like in `options.filter=""` but i'm not getting result with same number which has space in middle or anything which splits my filter string.

and also i need to know how fast will it do finding, because i need to load a page as soon as the document is ready and i need to change content instantly.

Help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter = ["displayName", "phoneNumbers"]; is an array right ?

Use this regualr expression to replace all white space

.replace(/\s/g,"");

and save the result values to a new array, then do the filtering.

Eg:
Declare an empty array.

Use a for to iterate through array.
find the number.
replace the white space.
store it to new array.

```
var number = '98 57 268 23';
number.replace(/\s/g,"");
```

---

```
number = 985726823
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry the number which im sending cam be modified like you said. but problem is the phone number format is unknown and  we can not change the number which is in phone. @KRIZTE

Comment: which plugin are you using?

Comment: org.apache.cordova.contacts @KRIZTE